# Grounding outdoor ceiling fan with EMT

Tags: electrical

This is a continuation of [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/238119/emt-to-outdoor-ceiling-fan), where I am asking about getting power to an outdoor ceiling fan.

I am using EMT and metal boxes for the rest of the install so that I don't need to run grounding wires, but the only ceiling fan rated *outdoor* box is [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B085HKSXMM), which is plastic.  It does have a grounding lug, but I assume that since the box is plastic, the EMT/box connection won't be grounded.

So, how do I go about grounding my ceiling fan box?  Can I use a "bonding bushing"?  Do raintight bonding bushings exist?

I'm not super concerned about raintight since this is fully under a porch, but if code requires it I will do it.

Photo of the new box:

[image]

Comment: What are you using for an EMT connector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to go to your last metal junction box and connect a bare copper wire or a green insulated wire to the box with a 10-32 grounding screw into one of the smaller holes in the box. Pull that wire to your plastic ceiling fan box. You could also pull the ground wire through the entire run but you'd still have to ground it in the last metal box.

Comment: OK that’s what I thought would be the case. Thanks!

Comment: You can't pull a ground wire the entire run... *well you can*, but you have to ground it at the *last* metal junction box.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Good catch.